# Container for image buttons

Tags: c#, button

What is the best way to create container for image buttons with scrollbar?
I would like to scroll between multiple image buttons ...

Thanks.

Comment: What platform your speak about?

Comment: Visual Studio - C# (sorry I didn't mention it before).

Comment: He means Windows Forms, ASP.NET or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a [Panel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and set the [ScrollableControl.AutoScroll Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  to `true`

Comment: Can I do it with Split Container, so I have image buttons on left and information about the image on the right side?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to set the AutoScroll property per Panel within the Split Container.